# How can I implement spell check in a WP7 text boxes

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can I implement spell check in a WP7 text boxes without using input scope of a text box

Answer (score 1):

You may use the TextChanged event and process the text entered on the TextBox for spelling checks. That would be my approach. But it will slow down your typing and UI mapping. Best method is to use the inputScope and let the device do its work which you do not want. I hope my answer helps you.